# Detecting similar objects using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've been looking into this for a while and was wondering the feasibility of using something like feature detection in OpenCV to do the following:

I'm working on a project that requires identifying items within a grocery store that do not have barcodes (i.e. produce). I want to build a local database of the various items to be identified and, using images of the items, compare them to the database and tell what the item is.

This doesn't need to be perfectly accurate (it doesn't need to tell between different types of apples, for example), but I want it to be able to tell between something like a peach and an orange, but still be able to tell a banana is a banana even though its color is slightly different.

My question is, is what I'm trying to do possible using OpenCV? From what I've been reading, identical objects can be tracked with relative ease, but I'm having trouble stumbling upon anything more like what I'm attempting to do.

Any nudges in the right direction would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Hi, this is not the place for such a question. It's much too broad. Come here if you have a specific coding issue you need help with.

Comment: Take a look at Convolutional Neural Nets. But OpenCV doesn't have CNN support, and training a CNN is not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Very open question, but OpenCV is where to be looking. Your best bet would probably be building Haar cascade classifiers. Plenty of reading material on the topic, somewhat overwhelming at first but that is what I would be looking into.

Comment: Thanks! The question was meant to be open as I'm just assessing my options for implementing this feature. I appreciate your response.

Comment: Follow up, how well with this run on a microcontroller such as a RasPi? I can tell that making the classifiers can be pretty intensive, but once they are created, how much processing power does it take to use the classifiers to detect the object?

Comment: it should be fine after you have the classifiers, from a quick google there are some demo face detection programs written already for the Pi that run well.